# Error trying to diff 'xx01'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, primeng

Suppose I'm receiving from an API an array of strings like ["xx01","xx02","xx03",..]. Which changes I should do here to have an autocomplete list (primeng) which works correctly.

I have this message error : ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'xx02'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

```
export class TaskComponent {

public sales: string[];
sale_A : string;
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private customer: CustomerService, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.customer.getSales().subscribe(result => {
        this.sales = result;
        console.log(this.sales);
    });
    this.buildForm();
}

onSelectSale(event) {
    this.sales = event;
}

searchSales(event) {
    this.customer.getSales().subscribe(result => {
        this.sales = result;
    });
}

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        sale_A: [{ value: ''}, Validators.required],
        sale_B: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                <p-autoComplete formControlName="sale_A"
                                inputStyleClass="form-control"
                                [dropdown]="true"
                                [(ngModel)]="sales"
                                [suggestions]="sales"
                                (onDropdownClick)="searchSales($event)"
                                (completeMethod)="searchSales($event)"
                                (onSelect)="onSelectSale($event)"
                                emptyMessage="no msg">
                    <ng-template let-title pTemplate="item">
                        <p>{{sales[0] | json}}</p>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-autoComplete>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think that If you are not using multiple selection you should use a sale object to store the selected sale `[(ngModel)]="selectedSale"`  -  `[suggestions]="sales"`